# Cannot review first posts and late answers because of vote limit

Tags: support, voting, review

So, I have reached my vote limit ($38$ because I probably only voted on $8$ questions), and I decided to check the reviews. I noticed that I could not access the "first posts" *and* "late answers" queue because I could not vote anymore for $5$ hours.

[image: Reviews]

Is it that I have to vote on reviews? Why can't I just comment on the posts, or click "No Action Needed"?

Comment: If you can't vote, that seriously limits your responses in these queues; thus it's better not to engage in the review queues until you're able to use all the necessary tools.

Comment: I must admit I vote on reviews about $75\%$ of the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not required to vote on the posts you review. However, if you are not able to use the full range of options in the queue, it is better to give the reviewer's role to someone who is. The system is set up to make sure this happens.